# How do I shift each row in an R dataframe by its row index

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    a   b   c
1   1   2   3
2   1   2   3
3   1   2   3
```

and want to transform it such that each row is shifted right based on its row index. So that the result looks like this:

```
    a   b   c
1   1   2   3
2   0   1   2
3   0   0   1
```

How do I achieve this in R?

Comment: hacky: `do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(i){dplyr::lag(df[i, ], i - 1, default = 0)}))`

Comment: im sure there is  a `data.table::shift` way to do this but I am tired

Comment: Relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143992

Comment: @RonakShah yes, re-opened, not exact dupe. Solutions could work if we set lower right triangle to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generalizing a little more, starting with the following data frame

```
a b c
1 1 2 3
2 1 2 3
3 1 2 3
4 1 2 3
5 1 2 3

t(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x){
                         shifted <- rep(0, min(x-1, ncol(df)))
                         if(ncol(df)>=x) shifted <- c(shifted, df[x,1:(ncol(df)-x+1)])
                         unlist(shifted)}))
     a b c
[1,] 1 2 3
[2,] 0 1 2
[3,] 0 0 1
[4,] 0 0 0
[5,] 0 0 0
```